# no notifications, revisions, responses for some of my threads

Tags: support

Why don't I have any Email notifications from some of threads, for ex.,

- [Windows Server 2008 - Connecting to 127.0.0.1](https://serverfault.com/questions/170476/windows-server-2008-connecting-to-127-0-0-1)

as well as entries in revisions or responses or activities lists either for "yesterday", or for "today", or for "this week" :

- https://serverfault.com/users/recent/47886?startdate=2010-08-08%2000:00:00z&enddate=2010-08-15%2023:59:59z&tab=responses#tab-top
- https://serverfault.com/users/recent/47886?startdate=2010-08-08%2000:00:00z&enddate=2010-08-15%2023:59:59z&tab=revisions#tab-top

while there were hundreds of revisions, responses, comments during the last 36 hours?

---

--------- Update1: 
@Kara Marfia,

> In at least one of those cases, it's
>   because I edited out a lot of
>   discussion/commentary text that was
>   not pertinent to the technical
>   question

No, it was not, I had no revisions/activities viewable before your editing. All in all there  was 1 or 2 entry(ies) on comment while there were over a hundred posts, updates, revisions, comments, answers

It is not my frustration. It is SF's problem based on creating catch-22:  new-comer does not have any access to any minimal functionality for participation below the score 100 thereby forcing him to trick away things (maintain posts in searchable, tractable, editable, manageable, formattable, readable answers) in a manner which has sense to him. Downvoting, closing, deleting, revising, insulting only aggravate this catch-33.

I had read FAQ many times. It is senseless to send me there. It does not help to anything

As far as I do not have access, at least, to see revision history, there is absolutely no sense in deleting my ramblings.

They irritate you? Not me.

There is no point to tell me about my irritation if it is yours and it is not me who create,  maintain and aggravate it to the point of absurdness.

---

--------- **Update2:**

It is completely crazy to insist to pass somebody's writings to become the property of others denying any access to it by the author (expecting that the author will delete its own discussions, history denying to them access to itself but permitting to view them to others). from any of possible angles - juridical, ethical, moral, common sense, etc.

---

--------- **Update3:**

Insisting to comment denying access to comments by downvoting, insisting to delete rabmlings denying access to my own writings but permitting the access by others.

**Hmmm, continue. But do not insist on calling your problems "my"**

**@Ben,**

No, revisions are not always available! In 95% of cases they were not available to me.

I can only guess what this availability depends on

---

--------- **Update4:**

My guess is that revisions become available only upon somebody's else editing my post

Comment: @vgv8 I appreciate that you are posting meta questions in the right place now.  Thank you! The goal of Serverfault, StackOverflow, SuperUser and all other StackExchange sites is to build a place where the best questions and answers for a topic can be found. Good posts are created by the whole community (editing, voting) and should be (meta discussion)noise-free.

Comment: @vgv8 - In reply to Update2, the revision history is available for everyone to view. It is always made clear if there is more than one revision, and your post will always be shown as the first revision, so people will know you created the content originally. Nobody is trying to take credit from you.

Comment: @vgv8 can you please provide a link to an answer you have posted where you believe you are not being shown the revision history.

Comment: @vgv8 - ALL revisions by *anybody* are tracked. If you edit your post, it will show a revision made by you. If I edit your post, it will show a revision by me. The only exception to this is if you edit your post multiple times within 5 minutes - if you do this, it will show all edits in that 5 minute period as your last revision. If however I edit in between this 5 minute period, it will then show a new revision entry for me, and if you edit subsequently, you will get another revision.

Comment: It's been obvious for a while (GregD's been pointing out for a couple days at least) that this vgv8 person just likes to argue and isn't trying to make any progress in understanding how SF works.  Maybe we can all just agree to close any future unclear or argumentative questions he posts?

Comment: Please, please use the comments (now you have > 50 rep) rather than updating your posts, though you can *always* comment on your own questions and answers to your own questions.

Answer (score 6):

In at least one of those cases, it's because I edited out a lot of discussion/commentary text that was not pertinent to the technical question.  It's an attempt to help you out.  You're getting downvoted in part because you're using the site in a manner that is contrary to the FAQ.

You're angry about the downvotes.  The community is irritated by the lengthy, rambling posts - and what appears to be an attempt to turn a Q&A site into a message board.

In anticipation of further outcry, please see the FAQ - particularly "Other people can edit my stuff?!"

Take a deep breath.  A lot of your frustration seems to stem from a lack of understanding about the site.  My suggestion is that you read some of the existing questions.  Try to get a feel for how the site was designed and how the community currently functions.

Comment: IMHO, some users need to just move on.  I've pointed vgv8 to the FAQs on several occasions, which has only ended in seemingly frustrating him or her further.  @vgv8 this is not the community you are looking for *waves hand*

Comment: Something tells me the Jedi mind trick isn't going to work on this kid. Funny, I thought it worked well on weak minded beings. Maybe you don't have enough midichlorians.

Answer (score 4):

You apparently want this Q@A site to function as a discussion forum, which it isn't. The FAQ, which you say you've read many times, makes that point very clear. Even the way you constantly edit your questions to add argumentative and irrelevant content makes it clear to me that you don't want to use a question and answer format.

This very "question" is a good example of the kind of irrelevant rambling and moaning you have become known for.

I think GregD's comment sums it up nicely: This is not the community you're looking for.